# Can i pass a variable which contains all parameters for a function to a function in python?If yes, then how?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, parameter-passing

Suppose there is the following function:

```
def write_form(username="", email="", username_error="", email_error="", password_error_one="", password_error_two="" ):
    response.out.write(user_signup_form %{ "username": username, 
                                                "email": email,
                                                "username_error" : username_error,
                                                "email_error" : email_error,
                                                "password_error_one" : password_error_one,
                                                "password_error_two" : password_error_two })
```

And i want to call in the following manner:

```
s='user_username,user_email, email_error="email_error", password_error_one="password_error_1"'
write_form(s)
```

Instead of:

```
write_form(user_username,user_email, email_error="email_error", password_error_one="password_error_1")
```

Is it possible to do so?If yes how?

Comment: You need to parse the string before you can use it. What format is it and where did it come from? Not particularly safe, but `eval('write_form(%s)' % s)` is an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary and then unpack it like this

```
s={"username":"username",
   "email":"a@b.com",
   "email_error":"email_error",
   "password_error_one":"password_error_1"}


def write_form(username="", email="", username_error="", email_error="",
        password_error_one="", password_error_two = ""):
    print username, email, email_error, password_error_one, password_error_two

write_form(**s)
```

Comment: Yes, you could do this. Or you could move this into a class.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question - he wants to pass in an unparsed string, not a dict.

Answer (score 1):

The classic solution to "my functions take a large number of parameters" is to move those parameters into an object, and make the function a method of that object.

It looks like you're processing web forms. There are a bunch of libraries that already exist to make this easier. Notably the Django framework has extensive libraries.